# JS google map modify listener from another class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm in the middle of converting my google map from ionic-native to JS. I'm trying to modify my map's click listener from another class. Howevever I'm getting property issues.

```
this.maps.init(); //Initialize map

this.maps.map.addListener('click', function(pos){

   this.maps.addMarker(pos.latLng.lat(), pos.latLng.lng());//error here

});
```

I'm getting the error

```
Cannot read property 'addMarker' of undefined
```

help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use arrow functions like this:

```
this.maps.init(); //Initialize map

this.maps.map.addListener('click', (pos) => {

   this.maps.addMarker(pos.latLng.lat(), pos.latLng.lng());//error here

});
```

By using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), the **this** property is not overwritten and still references the component instance.

Comment: it worksss i knew it was something stupid from me -_-

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved it! It's not something stupid, just something new... and we're all here to learn :)